# scp hangs after upload

Tags: centos, scp, hyper-v

**The Setup:**

When we use SCP on our CentOS Hyper-V VM to copy files to the target (SunOS) it gets to 100% and then hangs, not closing the connection. When we finally use `ctrl+C` to exit, the file on the remote end is empty.

The whole process works fine on very small files but if it's a few dozen lines, it starts to hang.

The CentOS box is using the default switch.

`SSH` works perfectly fine from and to the CentOS VM.

***Source***: CentOS 7.6 VM running on Hyper-V (Windows 10 Ent.)

***Destination***: SunOS 5.6 x64 Machine

**Log:**

```
scp -vvv tst.txt user@target.domain:/tmp/
...
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp/
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Missing locale support for LANG=en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 201600
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0664 12840 test.txt
test.txt                                                     100%   13KB   0.1KB/s   02:52
```

**strace**:

The relevant section is the following block, which is looped indefinitely when the file is of any significant size:

````
write(1, "\rtest.txt                       "..., 185) = 185
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, {0x555900a4ebf0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7fc354919280}, 8) = 0
alarm(1)                                = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
read(7, 0x7ffe718fdb0f, 1)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---```
````

Comment: Did you went through [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=scp+hangs+after+transfer)? I don't believe anyone can help you.

Comment: Scp makes an ssh connection to the remote system and starts another scp process there. One scp instance sends files and the other receives them. You should try to figure out what the two instances are doing when they seem to be hung. Try attaching a debugger (or `truss`) to the scp instance on the target to see if it's hung executing a system call or waiting for data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I should specify that ssh is working fine between the machines -- I'll add that to the post.

Comment: @Kenster I added the strace to the post. It seems to be stuck in a loop as that block is repeated until I kill it with `ctrl+c`. Any ideas on what this could mean?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with MTU when connecting via OpenVPN. I added in the OpenVPN config file:

mssfix 1200

Now everything works. The transfer no longer hangs at 100%.